# Pspad "File contents were changed. Reload?" dialog bug

Tags: editor

I've been using PsPad for quite some time now, always on Windows XP never a problem. But since I've upgraded to Windows7, PsPad is throwing the confirmation dialog "File contents were changed. Reload?" when it doesn't have to. I can reproduce this annoying message by: editing a file, saving it (to the fileserver win3k over a network), viewing that file/page in the browser, going back to PsPad to work on the file. After that last point it throws the dialog, while obviously nothing has changed in the meantime.

Does anybody experience the same bug? Is there something to do about it? PsPad forum has a thread about this, but no solution is provided there.

Comment: The bug occured in the latest version: 4.5.4. Just reverted to 4.5.3 (the one I've been previously using on XP) but the bug persisted.

Comment: Tried setting CheckDocChanged=0 (http://forum.pspad.com/read.php?2,53148,page=2#msg-55231) but that didn't help.

Comment: Update: Setting CheckDocChanged=0 does help, but you'll have to set it in the right file: somewhere in Docs and settings folder "AppData/Roaming/PSpad".

It helps but is not the solution, I think setting this options only makes sure PsPad doesn't check the file for changes. And so doesn't show the dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch it off in program settings / Direct edit button
CheckDocChanges=0

Comment: I can't find that button. Could you point me or send a screenshot? I had to edit a txt file to set this value to 0.

Answer (score 3):

> You can switch it off in program settings / Direct edit button CheckDocChanges=0

The DIRECT EDIT button it's **a button** to the left of the OK button on the program settings dialog box ( in version 4.5.4 ). It's not entirely intuitive but it's there alright if you look.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the time on your server and your workstations are not in sync. You can set your workstation to synchronize with the same timeserver as your server, which you will have to find out yourself or from your admin.

To change the time server on your workstation do the following

1. Open date and time
2. Go to Internet Time
3. Change Settings
4. Put in the server
5. Click update now and OK